# Finding a regular grammar for a given regular expression?

Tags: grammar, theory, context-free-grammar, regular-language

I am trying to find a regular grammar that generates the language given by the regular expression `((a+b∗c)d)∗`. Is there a general technique I can use to convert regular expressions into regular grammars?

Answer (score 1):

It's usually a lot easier to convert a finite automaton for a regular language into a regular grammar than it is to convert a regular expression into a regular grammar. I'd recommend starting off by building an automaton for the regular expression - either manually or by applying Thompson's algorithm to mechanically convert the regex to an automaton - and then doing the conversion from there.

Comment: Do i have to follow a method so that it will be easier? Where do i find

Comment: Start by thinking about how to convert a DFA into a regular grammar. I think you'll find that there's a close connection between transitions and productions and between accepting states and &epsilon;-productions.

Comment: yeah, got it. Thank you :)